# Why is my function returning an integer although I have specified the answer as a float?

Tags: c++

I am quite perplexed by how my answer is not giving me a float for this simple function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int average(int a[], int num){
    float avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        avg += a[i];
    }
    avg = avg / num;
    cout<<avg<<endl; //gives 1.5
    return avg;
}

int main(){
    int a[] = {1,2}; 
    float result = average(a, 2);
    cout<<result<<endl; //gives 1
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen in the comments, why would the output of the function be 1 when the final computed value is 1.5? I have also specified the answers to be returned in float form, so I don't really know why it still gives me an int.

Comment: `average` should return float, not int.

Comment: Yes indeed, but the output of `result` is 1 and not 1.5. This is the weird part..

Comment: `int average(int a[], int num)`  is the signature of a function returning `int`.

Comment: @leekwotsin Since the function returns an `int` - the result gets converted to it, impicitly, if possible. And in the case of `float` to `int` - such conversion is possible. Compiler may warn you about such conversion (since it is lossy), did you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: Go through link for return type for function http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have also specified the answers to be returned in float form, so I
>   don't really know why it still gives me an int.

Because `average` returns `int`, so your `float` (that you return in `average`) is casted to `int`, returned, then back to `float` and stored into `result`. Losing any precision because of the cast to `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't realized I declared my function as an int in the first place, so that is why.

Answer (score 3):

```
float average(int a[], int num){
    float avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        avg += a[i];
    }
    avg = avg / num;
    cout<<avg<<endl; //gives 1.5
    return avg;
}
```

You forget to specify return value type in function declaration as float.